# React TestUtils, type into textbox nor working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `React.js` and `Jasmine` to write a unit test for a text input element.  I'm trying to simply type into the input `React.TestUtils` and having no luck.  The purpose of the test it to limit the number of characters that can be placed in the text box.  When tested inside the application, the textbox quits accepting characters at the correct limit.

Text
// TextInput.js

```
 var React = require('react');

        var TextInput = React.createClass({
          handleChange: function(event) {
event.target.value]);
              if(event.target.value.length > 100){
                  value = event.target.value.substring(0,100);
                  return;
              }
            console.log("called");
            this.props.update(event.target.name, event.target.value.substring(0,100));
          },
          focus: function(event) {
            //console.log("Focusing on " + event.target.name);
            if(event.target.value === this.props.defaultValue)
              event.target.value = "";
          },
          blur: function(event) {
            //console.log("Blurring " + event.target.name);
            if(event.target.value === "")
              event.target.value = this.props.defaultValue;
          },
          render: function() {
            return <input type="text" name={this.props.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.props.value}
                className={this.props.className}
                title={this.props.title}

          }
        });

        module.exports = TextInput;
```

Test

```
describe('TextInput', function() {
    //..requires 
    var maxString="";
    var nums = "0123456789";
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  it('should only allow 100 characters in the title text', function() {

    var title = DataProperties.TitleTextInput;

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        maxString+=nums;
    }
      var text= TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TextInput id="txtTitleText" name="titleText"
          defaultValue="Default Title"
          placeholder="Enter a chart title"
          value=""
          className="form-input input-slim title_txt pre-active"
          title="Chart Title" />);
        console.log(text);
      TestUtils.Simulate.change(text, {target: {value: 'Hello, world'}});

  });
});
```

If I inspect text after the SimulateChange, I see that the value is not `Hello world`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this, too. `TestUtils.Simulate.change` doesn't actually change the `value` of the `<input/>`. It is merely dispatching an event. So `Simulate` is only for testing your event handler.

If you actually want to change the value of your `<input>`, you'll need to set it like this:

```
var textInput = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(text, 'input');
textInput.getDOMNode().value = 'Hello, world';
```